# Registered Partnership Clarification

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities, partner

My company is considering becoming a registered partner. I noticed Salesforce requires at least 1 person to have 2 Salesforce certifications. Do these need to be completed before we apply for a partnership, or do we have a window of time to fulfill this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers from the Q&A section from 'Updates to the Salesforce Partner Program for Consulting Partners (Beginning February 1, 2016)'

You find this at https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/New_Consulting_Partner_Changes_FAQ

> Q: Does Registered Tier require 2 certified individuals or 2
>   certifications? Can a company with 1 employee with 2 certifications
>   qualify to be a Registered Partner?
>
> A: Registered Tier requires a minimum of ONE individual (holding 2 or
>   more certifications), or a minimum of TWO individuals (holding at
>   least one certification each). The certifications that count toward
>   the requirement are Platform Developer1 (includes Dev 401 for FY17),
>   Sales Cloud, or Service Cloud.
>
> Q: Which certifications count for Registered Tier qualification?
>
> A: Developer, Sales Cloud, and Service Cloud certifications can be
>   applied towards the minimum requirement for Registered Tier. After
>   further analysis, we have removed the Advanced Administrator
>   certification from this list.
>
> Q: If we do not meet the minimum requirements for the Registered level
>   or above or we cannot pay the fee, can we still be considered a
>   partner in the Salesforce Partner Program?
>
> A: No, you will not be a partner in Salesforce Partner Program.
>
> Q: What happens if I enrolled and paid the program fee but have yet to
>   get my 2 certifications, will I still be removed?
>
> A: Yes, we will suspend all paid partners who do not yet have their 2
>   certifications. No refunds will be offered. Once you have your 2
>   certifications, you will then be reinstated